# Gensim: KeyedVectors.train()

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

I downloaded Wikipedia word vectors from [here](https://github.com/clips/dutchembeddings). I loaded the vectors with:

```
model_160 = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(wiki_160_path, binary=False)
```

and then want to train them with:

```
model_160.train()
```

I get the error back:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-22a9f6312119> in <module>()
----> 1 model.train()

AttributeError: 'KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'train'
```

My question is now:
It seems like KeyedVectors has no train function, but I want to continue training the vectors on my personal sentences, instead of just using the Wikipedia vectors. How is this possible?

Thanks in advance, Jan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use KeyedVectors for that.
From [the documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html):

> Word vector storage and similarity look-ups.
>   The word vectors are considered read-only in this class.

And [also](https://archive.is/3WugV#selection-305.0-445.157):

> The word vectors can also be instantiated from an existing file on disk in the word2vec C format as a KeyedVectors instance.
>   [...]
>   NOTE: **It is impossible to continue training the vectors loaded from the C format**
>   because hidden weights, vocabulary frequency and the binary tree is
>   missing.

Comment: is there anyway to train with some help from pretrained Google word2vec. ?